# Pointer memory allocation and delete

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, memory

I have a simple question regarding pointer management in C++.
When I am doing the following:

```
myTableWidget->setItem(j, i, new TableWidgetItem("something"));
```

if I understand well, I am creating a new pointer to a tablewidgetitem.
However, as I did not define any name, I cannot perform the `delete` operation.
So, this will stay in memory all the time my program is running, right? Or is it something I do not understand?

Another thing is the following.
Suppose I have a class which takes 2 `doubles` (for example `ComplexNumber` class). The desctructor of my class is empty. However, if I call `delete` on an element of my class `ComplexNumber`, is it going to delete this element in my memory or just call the destructor which is empty ? If this element stays in memory all the running time, how can I program properly to delete it when I want to change the values of my table?
Example below:

complex.h

```
class Complex
{
    public:
        double r;
        double i;

        Complex(double, double);
        ~Complex();

};
```

complex.cpp

```
Complex::Complex(const double& real, const double& imaginary): r(real), i(imaginary)
{

}
Complex::~Complex():
{

}
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
       Complex *a = new Complex a(2,3);
       delete a;
}
```

In this case, is my memory free of a (a is destroyed in my memory and the double 2 and 3 are deleted) or it just does nothing as my destructor is empty?

Comment: Re: "I am creating a new pointer to a tablewidgetitem" -- no, the code creates a new `TableWidgetItem` **object**; the result of the `new` operator is a pointer to that object. Don't muddle objects and pointers; they're two different things. Pointers usually point to objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are talking about [`QTableWidget::setItem`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setItem), then observe the documentation state "The table takes ownership of the item." This means the table object is responsible for destroying the item when it's no longer needed.

---

`delete` expression does two things. First, it runs the destructor of the object pointed to by its operand. Then, it deallocates memory pointed to by its operand. In your example, the allocated memory is indeed freed.

Comment: I updated my question with a simple example. Thank you for your answer about QTableWidget. Does that mean that when I "surcharge" an item, the previous one is deleted in memory ?

Comment: I guess by "surcharge" you mean "replace". Yes, I would expect `setItem` to destroy the previous item when the new one is set. To convince yourself, conduct an experiment - have `TableWidgetItem`'s destructor print or log something, so you can observe where and when it's called.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers to my "simple" questions. I now understand better what is happening behind the delete expression